# Skype on iPhone - does phone have to be awake / unlocked to receive calls?

Tags: iphone, applications, skype

I have just installed the Skype app on my iPhone 5 running iOS 10.3.3.

To recieve Skype calls does the phone have to be awake/unlocked?

Does the Skype app have to be open/launched? I periodically double click the home button and close / swipe up all open apps. I presume if I do this to Skype I can't receive calls?

To receive calls does the Skype app have to be the currently open app? Or can I use other apps, with Skype open in the "background"?

Comment: Which version of iOS are you using?

Comment: version 10.3.3 .

Answer (score 1):

Skype doesn’t have to be open. I have tested it. There have been known issues with this which you may be experiencing.

In iOS 11 a feature was introduced that enhances third-party calling, so updating should fix the issue.

Comment: Does an iPhone have to be awake/unlocked to receive Skype calls?

Comment: Did you test this with iOS 10.3, or with a more recent version?

Comment: I'm waiting for a Skype call - my first ever one - so I don't know if I need to keep my phone awake/unlocked, with Skype running and the 'open' app (not in the background)

Comment: @Markeee There is always the option of creating a temporary account on another device and use this to call your iPhone (so you can play around with various scenarios). 3rd party calling apps can embed themselves in recent versions of iOS, not sure whether this was possible with 10.3 already (or whether Skype supports it).

Comment: @nohillside iOS12, just remembered a feature in iOS 11 was introduced to enhance third-party calling.

Comment: @Markeee try updating your OS